# How do I repopulate user info in a Django form?

Tags: python, django

Previsouly, I used forms.ModelForm to create a Django form and in **views.py** used:

```
p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                  instance=request.user.profile)
```

This way, if the form was not valid when submitted, it would repopulate the information the user entered previously. This saved a user from having to enter the information again.

I have since changed to forms.Form because I can't figure out how to customize Crispy Forms using forms.ModelForm, but now if I call **instance=request.user.profile**, I get an error.

What can I do to repopulate the information the user previously placed in the form so they do not have to do it again?

Comment: I think it might make more sense to just fix the problem with crispy forms when you use a modelform. Can you share what goes wrong? Normally crispy forms work quite well with `ModelForm`s, so I guess this is a small problem you somehow have.

Comment: You can make use of `initial`, but this will only make the problems harder in the future.

Comment: I fixed my code so that it shouldn't be an issue when submitting. I just figured this was an extra step just in case something didn't work right during submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate the fields of a form with the [**`initial=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial), this then contains a dictionary that maps the fields to the corresponding value.

So if your form for example is defined as:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    age = forms.IntegerField()
```

you can construct a form with:

```
ProfileUpdateForm(initial={'name': 'Jason G', 'age': 25})
```

A `ModelForm` basically does the same, except that here it obtains the initial values form the `instance=…` parameter, and thus obtains attributes from that object and passes these to the corresponding form fields.

That being said, normally crispy forms work quite well with `ModelForm`s, so perhaps it is better to take a look what the problem is with your `ModelForm`s and try to fix this over "circumventing" the problem, but making it harder to work with your forms.

Comment: Thank you. As always, your answers are extremely helpful. I believe I have fixed all issues with form submission and you're right, I should've looked at what the problem was instead of trying to circumventing it. Thank you!

Comment: Willem - How would I repopulate the fields if someone wants to edit their profile?

Comment: @JasonG: you can make a dictionary with `initial={'name': userprofile.name, 'age': userprofile.age}`.

Comment: Does this look correct? I just added Test to see if it would populate (which it doesn't) form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, initial={'first_name': 'Test'})

Comment: Once I remove request.POST and request.FILES, then *initial* will populate the fields, however, I need request.POST and request.FILES to store to the database.

Comment: @JasonG: you can use `ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, intial=...)` I think.

Comment: Unfortunately crispy forms doesn't populate with that. I was able to set all fields to value={ user.profile.[field] } and that worked. Of course, now my form.is_valid() is returning false, so I'll have to figure that out.